# Is praying for the wealth of the Stocks Exchange blasphemy?

Tags: prayer, blasphemy, economics

In the news I saw an American politician praying for growing stock market prices. Isn't this considered blasphemy, according to Christian beliefs, like praying to the golden calf?

Comment: According to Matthew 6:5 it's wrong to make prayer a public spectacle so as to draw attention to oneself.

Comment: to OP, this question shouldn't specifically name anyone. It makes it controversial and too localized, all in one go. [Should questions avoid specifically naming people?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/468)

Comment: The question has been unlocked. Feel free to edit if you feel it necessary. I'll let the community reopen it.

Comment: To me this is still too broad: "Christian beliefs" is the only scope.  Perhaps biblical basis one way or the other would be more appropriate.

Comment: The question was more narrow when it had the reference to the politican Perry who called to pray in a stadium, broadcastet by TV stations in the pre-election phase about 5 years ago, but here I was accused of outing him (LOL).

Answer (score 13):

Praying TO something is different than praying FOR something, so I don't think there is a good way to make a connection to the golden calf issue.

That being said, that seems like a very selfish prayer to make. It is quite possible that such a prayer shows that that money and success (individual or corporate) has become an idol. The example prayer we have to follow in the Lords prayer directs us to pray for just what we need ... our daily bread ... and that God's will be done.

> **[Matthew 6:9–13](http://www.esvbible.org/search/+Matthew+6:9%E2%80%9313/)** (ESV)
>   Pray then like this:
>   “Our Father in heaven, hallowed be your name. Your kingdom come, your will be done, on earth as it is in heaven. Give us this day our daily bread, and forgive us our debts, as we also have forgiven our debtors. And lead us not into temptation, but deliver us from evil.

Comment: +1. A much more appropriate prayer would be for the welfare and physical security of the nation or the world. If that's worked out by a booming stock market, great. If not, so be it. We should be praying for the true ends, not specific means.